# How to align ListTile vertically in a Container

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

I want to align the `ListTile` vertically in the middle of the container. Horizontally, it should stay aligned to the left.

What I have now is this:
[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Expanded Column Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 15),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                },
                child: Container(
                    height: 35,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      gradient: const LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          colors: [Color(0xFFfe4a32), Color(0xFFcf1502)],),
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: const Text(
                        "Some text",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            color: Color(0xFFfe4a32),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                      trailing: 
                         const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_drop_down_outlined,
                          color: Color(0xFFfe4a32),
                          size: 35,
                        ),
                      
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only remove the `height` of the container. It'll do the work for you.
But if you also want to decrease the height of the current `Container`,
Put `dense:true` and `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero` inside the `ListTile` along with removing the `height` of the `Container`.

Or, if you aren't satisfied with the above outputs, you should try using `Row` and `Column` for creating `ListTile` like widget.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Ankeet! Even with `dense:true` and `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero`, there is still space between the top of the Container and the text. Isn't there any other way to push the text up (except for `Row` and `Column`?

Comment: Have you removed the height of the container ? If you did, and didn't get the UI as per expectation, then you should use Row/Column. There might be other solutions as well, but I'm not quite aware of them.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like so:

```
child: ListTile(
   title: Transform(
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -6, 0.0),
         child: const Text(
```